# Python, Cygwin - ImportError: No module named _psycopg

Tags: python, postgresql, cygwin, 64-bit, psycopg2

I used the article on https://github.com/nwcell/psycopg2-windows and https://bitbucket.org/topper/psycopg2-win64-py27/overview to get psycopg2 installed and working on Python2.7 and Cygwin.

The install ran fine and i see the package in the /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2-2.5.3-py2.7.egg/ directory.

However the import does not work.. Any idea on this error?

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul 25 2014, 14:04:36)
[GCC 4.8.3] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import psycopg2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2-2.5.3-py2.7.egg/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
ImportError: No module named _psycopg
```

Thanks,
Manish

Comment: I see the -rw-r--r--  1 sacace Domain Users 1830400 Feb 15 15:57 _psycopg.pyd file in the C:\cygwin64\lib\python2.7\site-packages\psycopg2-2.5.3-py2.7.egg\psycopg2 directory. Not sure why is it unable to find it

Comment: Same issue and no solution, yet. Should we switch to Cygwin 32 bits even on a 64 bits system?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this exact set of messages -- but not in my local Cygwin/Babun dev environment -- I got them when I pushed to the RHEL 7 server to test there.  It took two days to flush it out, and how I solved it likely doesn't apply to you.  But I learned some things that probably do.

Another cause of this error is argued at great length in these bug reports (with Python and psycopg pointing fingers at each other) -- and generally not worth the read -- read on below instead:

- http://bugs.python.org/issue16047
- https://psycopg.lighthouseapp.com/projects/62710/tickets/201

The gist of it?  Look for some updates -- it looks like they both might have made some small changes that affect this.

Anyway... this is how I installed **psycopg2** in Cygwin (assuming Babun's **pact** installer is available):

- `pact install libpq-devel`
- `pip install psycopg2`

Yup, that's it!  (Some envs might also require a C compiler and python*-devel.)

An alternative to installing **libpq-devel** is to install Windows Postgres and add the location of its `pg_config` file to your PATH so that **pip** can compile **psycopg2** -- but installing **libpq-devel** from the Cygwin shell is cleaner and it puts its `pg_config` where **pip** can already find it.

I installed **pyscopg2** from within a virtual env but that shouldn't have mattered.  What might matter, however, could be one of the following:

- Python version: You were using 2.7.8 (almost the latest for the time), I was using 3.4.3.  Try a later version of 2.7.
- **psycopg2** version:  You were using 2.5.3, I was using 2.6.1.
- Conflicting Python installs.  Check the `sys.path` values from within Python to make sure it looks as you would expect.  This doesn't appear to be your problem according to what you posted, but I mention it because this was ultimately my problem on RHEL 7 and how Apache was loading the virtual envs. ---- (Just another note here: I ultimately resolved the RHEL problem by compiling another **mod_wsgi** for Python 3.4.3, as per their instructions, to match my virtual envs.  The previous **mod_wsgi** was running under Python 2.7.5 and that version was failing to import `_psycopg` from a C library.  Besides, I didn't want 2.7 running at all.)

Answer (score 1):

It's mandatory to install `libpq`, which sometimes is not installed as part of `libpq-devel`. As of now, I succedded installing `libpq5`.

Comment: Works perfectly, but only on python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

Env = python 2.7.10 (cygwin distribution), Windows 7, Cygwin 64

1) pip install psycopg2 failed as I didn't have pip 
debug

2) Installed pip from here: pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

3) pip install psycopg2 failed due to 'no pg_config...'

4) psycopg2 installer for win (www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/) failed cause I am using cygwin's python install, not the python in the machine's registry and this installer won't allow user to install anywhere else other thatn the python that is registred with Windows 
(Installer succeeded, but the files were not where I needd them.)
("Copying" the files didn't work.)

5) This (https://github.com/nwcell/psycopg2-windows) pip install "worked" (gave no errors) but when I tried to import, I got the message:
"ImportError: No module named psycopg2"

6) pip uninstall psycopg2

7) Tried to pip install libpq-dev and python-dev
"Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libpq-dev (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for libpq-dev"

8) installed Postgres & pg_config from here http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#windows

9) added pg_config to path

10) pip install psycopg2 now worked

11) import psycopg2 in .py file caused core dump

Stack trace:
Frame        Function    Args
006001A5A60  0018007261A (000FFFFE3F4, 0000000E514, 00000000000, 000FFFFDE50)
006001A5B00  00180073DD0 (00077801FD6, 00000000000, 00000000140, 00000000000)
006001A5D50  0018012EF8F (00600010540, 00000000000, 003DB05FDB0, 6FFFFF28050)
006001A6040  0018012BC70 (0000000000D, 00000000000, 00000000000, 0018013D7DA)
00000000000  0018012C139 (006001A6030, 3630303030303030, 3036303030303030, 00000
00000B)
00000000000  0018012C30C (00000000000, 10000000A8E73, 6F007000650072, 61006C0074
0072)
00000000000  00180127BFB (00000000000, 10000000A8E73, 6F007000650072, 61006C0074
0072)
00000000000  00180071169 (01000000010, 00000000000, 00000000000, 000FFFFCE00)
000FFFFAA00  00180073D11 (B64000B00630079, 00000000088, 1D17578E1C375D4, 1D17578
E16661AE)
52004F00520052  64006F00630072 (00000000088, 1D17578E1C375D4, 1D17578E16661AE, 1
D175A09055FB4F)
52004F00520052  70002E00730065 (1D17578E1C375D4, 1D17578E16661AE, 1D175A09055FB4
F, 1D175A09055FB4F)
52004F00520052  B64000B00630079 (1D17578E16661AE, 1D175A09055FB4F, 1D175A09055FB
4F, 0000000180B)
52004F00520052  00000000088 (1D175A09055FB4F, 1D175A09055FB4F, 0000000180B, 0000
0002000)
52004F00520052  1D17578E1C375D4 (1D175A09055FB4F, 0000000180B, 00000002000, 01A0
0000020)
52004F00520052  1D17578E16661AE (0000000180B, 00000002000, 01A00000020, 45001600
000000)
52004F00520052  1D175A09055FB4F (00000002000, 01A00000020, 45001600000000, 4E004
500540058)
End of stack trace (more stack frames may be present)

(The above took ~2 days.)

12) pip install pg8000 worked

13) imported pg8000 to .py file and connected to DB
(Steps 12 and 13 took ~20 minutes.)

Answer (score 0):

You must use `Cygwin package installer` to install BOTH of the two packages：

- `libecpg6`, for `psycopg2` runtime library support, without it you will get
  `'ImportError: No module named _psycopg' when you run your script.`
- `libecpg-devel`, for compiling `psycopg2` without it you will get a lot of
  such as `pthread_***` errors when you install psycopg2 using pip tool.

As time goes on, those package name may be changed, but you should know what's
you deficiency.